# (String formatting) Is this what you call right justified and how do I get number to align "right justified"? Python 3.4

Tags: python-3.x

```
print('''
     a        b        a**b
     1        2        1 
     2        3        8
     3        4        81  
     4        5        1024 
     5        6        15625\n''')
```

Alright so in the code above, if you look at the third column, the numbers are aligned by let's say a left margin. In the code below however, aligns itself by a right margin. How do I get the code below to look like the code above? Also, is the problem I am talking about called right/left justification? I'm not sure what to call it. Ive also added the output of what Im getting for the for loop.

```
a = 1
b = 2
i = 0

for i in range(0,5):
    print("%10i%9i%9i" %(a,b, (a**b)))
    a+=1
    b+=1

 '''output:
     1        2        1
     2        3        8
     3        4       81
     4        5     1024
     5        6    15625'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Here is a simple fix using the `%` operator:

using the `%` to format a string, if you place a `-` after the `%` it will signify a left align. for your code, this would look like:

```
a = 1
b = 2
i = 0

for i in range(0,5):
    print("%10i%9i%-9i" %(a,b, (a**b)))
    a+=1
    b+=1

 '''output:
     1        21
     2        38
     3        481
     4        51024
     5        615625'''
```

As you can see, this left aligned all the way up to the previous column, the cheapest fix is to add nine spaces, but you can also just format an empty string with nine spaces as below (although with the character offsets, 8 space padding might be more correct):

```
a = 1
b = 2
i = 0

for i in range(0,5):
    print("%10i%9i%9s%-9i" %(a,b,"", (a**b)))
    a+=1
    b+=1

 '''output:
     1        2         1
     2        3         8
     3        4         81
     4        5         1024
     5        6         15625'''
```

## Best Solution: using the `str.format` module

Typically, I like using the `string.format` [module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html). It is pretty powerful and more succinct than the last example:

```
a = 1
i = 0
b = 2
for i in range(0,5):
    print("{0:<10}{1:<9}{2:<9}".format(a,b,(a**b)))
    a+=1
    b+=1

'''output:
     1         2        1        
     2         3        8        
     3         4        81       
     4         5        1024     
     5         6        15625 '''
```